# не понимаю, что пропустил в do loop помогите начинающему

Tags: c, cs50

```
water.c:8:1: error: expected identifier or '('
do
^

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)

int n, b, t;

do
{
    printf("Minutes: %i", n);
    n = get_int();
}
while (n < 0);

 b = 12;
 t = b * n;

{
printf("Bottlses: %i\n ", t);
}
```

Comment: Не забудьте нажать зелёную галочку возле ответа, который вам помог

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум у вас нет фигурных скобок вокруг тела `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    int n, b, t;

    do
    {
        printf("Minutes: %i", n);
        n = get_int();
    }
    while (n < 0);

    b = 12;
    t = b * n;

    printf("Bottlses: %i\n ", t);
}
```

Comment: о да, спасибо, не так очевидно на первый взгляд.)

Comment: @DenisDekar, очевидно - если всё-таки читать учебник перед тем как писать код.